# How to center the subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I use the subfigure to put two figures together, however they are not centered.

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 block/.style = {circle, draw,
    text width=1em,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
    line/.style = {draw,thick, -latex},
  service/.style={align=left, text width=0.5cm},
node distance=1.0cm and 0.4cm
]

% Place nodes
\node[block](s0){$0$};
\node[service, right of= s0, xshift=10mm, text width=3cm](s10){};
\node[block, below of = s0](s1){$1$};
\node[block, below of =s1](s2){$2$};
\node[block, right of =s2] (s3){$3$};
\node[block, below of =s2] (s4){$4$};
\path [line] (s0)--(s1);
\path [line] (s1)--(s2);
\path [line]  (s1)-|(s3);
\path [line] (s2)--(s4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{1}
\label{fig:workflowsim}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 block/.style = {circle, draw,
    text width=1em,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
line/.style = {draw,thick, -latex},
  service/.style={align=left, text width=0.5cm},
node distance=1.0cm and 0.4cm
]

% Place nodes
\node[block](s2){$0$} ;
\node[service, right of=s2,xshift=10mm, text width=3cm](s10){};
\node[block, below of =s2] (s4){$4$};
\node[block, below of =s4] (s6){$6$};
\node[block, right of =s6] (s7){$S7$};
\path [line] (s2)--(s4);
\path [line] (s4)--(s6);
\path [line] (s4)-|(s7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And it shows me the figure as below
[image]

As you can see the left figure is not on top of a(1) (the caption), it is left-align.
It is similar to the right figure.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Try to comment node `s10`.

Comment: Put an `fbox` around the tikzpicture. `\fbox{<wholeTikz Env>}`. You are setting the width of the nodes reserving space on the right hand side.

Comment: @Johannes_B if put \fbox, still cannot work

Comment: @sweetyBaby Wasn't suppose to work. It should merely show that the picture is centered, but that an  invisible node made it look uncentered. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a node which affects the centering, even if it's not visible.

- If you don't need the node, remove it.
- If you would like to keep the node, add the `overlay` option so it won't take space:

  ```
  \node[overlay, service, right of= s0, xshift=10mm, text width=3cm] (s10) {};
  ```

This `overlay` method is similarly useful for removing such an undesired shifting effect of arrows, so the space they cover won't count.